# Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1, 32, 340] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

This is the question:

Before we define the model, we define the size of our alphabet. Our alphabet consists of lowercase English letters, and additionally a special character used for space between symbols or before and after the word. For the first part of this assignment, we don't need that extra character.

Our end goal is to learn to transcribe words of arbitrary length. However, first, we pre-train our simple convolutional neural net to recognize single characters. In order to be able to use the same model for one character and for entire words, we are going to design the model in a way that makes sure that the output size for one character (or when input image size is 32x18) is 1x27, and Kx27 whenever the input image is wider. K here will depend on particular architecture of the network, and is affected by strides, poolings, among other things. A little bit more formally, our model   , for an input image    gives output energies  =() . If  ∈ℝ32×18 , then  ∈ℝ1×27 . If  ∈ℝ32×100  for example, our model may output  ∈ℝ10×27 , where    corresponds to a particular window in   , for example from  0,9  to  32,9+18  (again, this will depend on the particular architecture).

The code:

```
# constants for number of classes in total, and for the special extra character for empty space
ALPHABET_SIZE = 27, # Extra character for space inbetween 
BETWEEN = 26


print(alphabet.shape) # RETURNS: torch.Size([32, 340])
```

My CNN Block:

```
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

"""

Remember basics:
1. Bigger strides = less overlap
2. More filters = More features

Image shape = 32, 18
Alphabet shape = 32, 340

"""



class SimpleNet(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cnn_block = torch.nn.Sequential( 
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2)
          )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cnn_block(x)
        # after applying cnn_block, x.shape should be:
        # batch_size, alphabet_size, 1, width
        return x[:, :, 0, :].permute(0, 2, 1)



model = SimpleNet()


alphabet_energies = model(alphabet.view(1, 1, *alphabet.shape))

def plot_energies(ce):
    fig=plt.figure(dpi=200)
    ax = plt.axes()
    im = ax.imshow(ce.cpu().T)
    
    ax.set_xlabel('window locations →')
    ax.set_ylabel('← classes')
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top') 
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    
    cax = fig.add_axes([ax.get_position().x1+0.01,ax.get_position().y0,0.02,ax.get_position().height])
    plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax) 
    
plot_energies(alphabet_energies[0].detach())
```

I get the error in the title at alphabet_energies = model(alphabet.view(1, 1, *alphabet.shape))

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should begin to replace nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3) to nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3)

Your model begins with a conv2d from 3 channels to 32 but your input image has only 1 channel (greyscale image).

Comment: It is a color image. So it will have three channels in it.

Comment: Oh okay. Then what's in alphabet ? Especially this line : alphabet.view(1, 1, *alphabet.shape). 

From pytorch doc : torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size)
So you're not passing the image to the model ?

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused. Your alphabet variable is your image of size 32x340 (so greyscale ?) which you pass to the model which needs a 3 channels input.